# Borrar todos los datos de una tabla SQLite

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo una lista de elementos en una tabla de SQLite, pero no veo la manera de borrarlos todos al presionar un botón.

Mi base de datos:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    
    SQLiteConnection dbConn;
    public DataAccess()
    {
        dbConn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        // create the table(s)
        
        dbConn.CreateTable<Rapidas>();
    }

    

    public List<Rapidas> GetAllRapidas()
    {
        return dbConn.Query<Rapidas>("Select * From [Rapidas]");
    }
    public int SaveRapidas(Rapidas aListas)
    {
        return dbConn.Insert(aListas);
    }
    public int DeleteRapidas(Rapidas aListas)
    {
        return dbConn.Delete(aListas);
    }
    public int EditRapidas(Rapidas aListas)
    {
        return dbConn.Update(aListas);
    }


}
```

Código del botón que, al presionarlo, debe borrar toda la tabla:

```
private async void BorrarItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool accepted = await DisplayAlert("Borrar registros", "ESTÁS SEGURO?", "SÍ", "NO");
        
        if (accepted)
        {
            LottieBorrar.Play();
            
        }
        
    }
```

Cómo puedo hacer para borrar todo el listado de elementos de la tabla "Rapidas", al lanzar "BorrarItem_OnClicked".

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Se elimina de la siguiente forma: (Es un ejemplo)

```
public void deleteAll() { 
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    // db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null); 
    //db.execSQL("delete * from"+ TABLE_NAME); 
    db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME); 
    db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: No soy capaz de adaptarlo a mi código, podrías modificar el ejemplo con mis datos?

Comment: dbConn.delete(Rapidas, null, null);

Comment: He editado la pregunta con el código del evento de click de botón. No entiendo cómo debo hacer la llamada con la información que me has dado. Lo siento, estoy muy verde y no lo veo...

Comment: Esto provocarìa un error, debemos tener cuidado al definir el Query